# Modify tan(x) function to be sharper

Tags: functions

On the right is `-tan(x) + Pi/2` function. On the left is a function i am trying to create which is a "sharper" version of the function on the right.

[image: 1]

Any idea how to get the left function ? It doesn't have to be a modified version of `tan` but i think it is easier this way, i could be wrong.

Comment: Do you want your function to pass through $(-1, \pi)$?

Comment: @Regret yes, i especially do

Comment: Maybe $\pi/2-\tan(x^3)$

Comment: @Regret i edited my question it is -tan(x) + Pi/2, and i need it to pass from those 3 points i showed (−1,pi), (0,pi/2), (1,0)

Comment: How comes that $-\tan(1)+\frac{\pi}{2}=0$? (I am referring to the first graphics that seems to pass through $(1,0)$).

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat this is really close to what i need, if not exactly :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio um you are right, but it is very close tan(1) = 3,114/2

Comment: So the other graphics must pass through $(-1,\pi)$ or $(-\arctan\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should go through the points $(-1,\pi), (0, \frac\pi2), (1,0)$. It is quite easy to see why. It is also just $\tan$ scaled and translated, so the general shape is the same.

$$f(x)=(\tan(1)-\tan(x))\frac{\pi}{2\tan(1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the way, your first function is $y = \tan \left(-x\right)+\frac{\pi }{2}$

Try $y=\frac12\tan(-x)+\frac\pi2$

The "amplitude" is less so it will "grow" slower.  Very precise terminology :D

Comment: i need my function to pass from the points i showed

Comment: Ok.  Make the period slightly less.  Solving the equation for its zeros you can find that $\tan(-x) = -\pi$.  So, $x = \arctan(\pi)$.  The function crosses the x-axis at $\arctan(\pi)$, but you want it to cross at 1, so you can change the period so it is shorter.

Comment: So the equation becomes $y=\frac{1}{2}\tan \left(-\arctan \left(\pi \right)x\right)+\frac{\pi }{2}$

Comment: @dardeshna: $+1$ for having a function scaled horizontally rather than vertically that still goes through the same (important) points!